# parskip inside of beamer blocks

Tags: beamer

I need to change `\parskip` inside of a beamer block in a manner which affects only the text but not the header or the distance between body and header. I am not managing. When I modify `\parksip` I also get a larger distance from the header. If I compensate for this with negative space, then this affects blocks which begin with, say, an itemize.

One of my dozens non-working minimal example is like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[]{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{}{\parskip 0.3cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{alertblock}{Head 1}
Bodyline 1

Bodyline 2
\end{alertblock}

\begin{alertblock}{Head 2}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here I get the `\parskip`as I need it between Bodyline 1 and Bodyline 2, but it adds an unwanted parskip between Head 1 and Bodyline 1. If I compensate for this with negative space, The first example works but then Item 1 moves up towards Head 2, which I do not want.

I tested several kinds of variants and always end up with some unwanted sideeffect.

What I want actually is quite simple: A normal block header and then, in the body of the block, a non-zero parskip.

Comment: I use `\medskip` and `\bigskip` for local adjustments, e.g. `Bodyline 1\medskip\par Bodyline 2`. For more flexible distances, use `\vspace{2mm}`.

Comment: @gernot I am not looking for local adjustments but for changes to the block environment as such. I do not want to manually adjust all instances but want the system to do it right by itself.

Comment: Have you tried removing this extra space right after?
`\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\setlength{\parskip}{0.3cm}\vspace{-\parskip}}`